# access openshift console from the host machine

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I installed openshift origin (one node cluster) on ubuntu server hosted on vbox on my local machine, I need to access it through web using its IP from my host machine(client) but it always redirect my Ip to local host 172.0.0.1, how to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

sudo oc cluster up --public-hostname=YourMachineIP